# print out error message in the panel of my html page

Tags: javascript, html

I want to print out a series of error messages on my html page based on what the user enters such as password, user name, address etc., which the information failed to validate.

My code looks like this:

```
    function validate(){
        var x,y,z;
        x = document.getElementById("name").value;
        if (x.length<6){
                text="user name too short";
        } else {
            text="validated";
        }       
        document.getElementById("aka").innerHTML = text;
    }
```

Now I can only validate one input. In this case the input with id "name".
I want to validate all the inputs like password also in this function.

How could I implement that in the function?

I tried adding more `if` statement followed by another `document.getElementById("aka").innerHTML = text`, but didnt work and the first didn't print out.

Comment: Whip something up something on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so we have a working example. We're developers, not magicians!

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable and put all the error messages there. Once you have finished, put the value of that variable in the `innerHTML` of the element you want.

```
function validate(){
    var x, errors = "";

    x = document.getElementById("name").value;
    if (x.length<6){
            errors += "user name too short<br />";
    }

    x = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (x.length<6){
            errors += "password too short<br />";
    }

    document.getElementById("aka").innerHTML = errors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either store all messages inside text variable

```
var text = "";
if (x.length<6){
     text+="user name too short";
} 

if(y.lenght<6) {
     text+= 'pwd too short';
}     
document.getElementById("aka").innerHTML = text;
```

Other option would be using [DOM functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) as follows:

```
document.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
```

```js
var text ="";
text += "user name too short";
text += "<br/>pwd too short";

document.getElementById('out1').innerHTML=text;


document.getElementById('out2').appendChild(document.createTextNode('user name too short'));
document.getElementById('out2').appendChild(document.createTextNode('pwd too short'));
```

```html
<div id="out1"></div>
<div id="out2"></div>
```